# Why css margin hide the image on click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to scroll my images using **next** and **previous** button. I used **CSS** to do the thing. I am setting the margin of `ul` to get next and previous image
but when I click on next button it hides my image instead of showing the next image. Could you please tell me how to show next image ?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    alert('next');
    $('.outer ul').css('margin-left', '200px');
  });
  $('#pre').click(function() {
    alert('pre');
    $('.outer ul').css('margin-left', '-200px');
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden
}
.outer ul {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.outer li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 195px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd">
    </li>

  </ul>
  <button id='pre'>
    previous
  </button>
  <button id='next'>
    next
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: why are you not using carousel https://amazingcarousel.com/examples/, http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp it has different options to play with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
var nextprevmargin = 0;
$('#next').click(function(){
    nextprevmargin = parseInt(nextprevmargin) - 200;
    $('.outer ul').css('margin-left',nextprevmargin + 'px');
})
$('#pre').click(function(){
    nextprevmargin = parseInt(nextprevmargin) + 200;
    $('.outer ul').css('margin-left',nextprevmargin + 'px');
})

})
```

here is fiddle for you. 
https://jsfiddle.net/urLdLdLm/9/
You have to add your counter check for prevention of scroll to be go out of screen

Comment: hello can we disable previous and next buttn.when user on last image can we disable next button or can we disable previous button when user on first image

Comment: yes you can achieve it by counting all images and add counter variable. I can do this for you. But you should try it yourself to master it. cheers

Comment: ok can you pls do ..I am trying I will update you if I will do first

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `+=200` and `-=200` values as the parameter of `.css()` methods.

```js
$(function(){

$('#next').click(function(){
alert('next');
console.log()
$('.outer ul').css('margin-left','-=200')
$
})
$('#pre').click(function(){
alert('pre')
$('.outer ul').css('margin-left','+=200')
})

})
```

```css
.outer {
width:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.outer ul {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.outer li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:195px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
        <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA"></li>
        <li><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
    
    </ul>
     <button id='pre'>
    previous
    </button>
    <button id='next'>
    next
    </button>
   
</div>
```

Comment: hello can we disable previous and next buttn.when user on last image can we disable next button or can we disable previous button when user on first image

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `.css('margin-left','200px')` or `.css('margin-left','-200px')`, you're setting the margin left to that value, not adding or subtracting from the current value.

Also, the next button should be subtracting, not adding and vice versa for the previous button.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvsb6asa/) of it working.

You're gonna need to set some bounds on this as well, so that the user doesn't add or subtract from the margin-left ad infinitum.

Comment: hello can we disable previous and next buttn.when user on last image can we disable next button or can we disable previous button when user on first image

Comment: You can. Try it yourself.